# registerClass error Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I understand correctly, in my TableView, I can't use

```
if (cell == nil)
{ 
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
}
```

if I declare the ReuseIdentifier in the Storyboard.

That's why I would like to declare the identifier in a class. But I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried with this :

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"carTableCell"];
```

But it tells me that

> No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual method name is `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` -- no "With".

Comment: `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` is for `UICollectionView`